# How to generate valgrind suppressions without manual cut and paste?

Tags: valgrind

I want to generate a suppressions file with `--gen-suppressions` in valgrind.

However, I do not want to have to go through thousands of lines of output the cut and paste out the suppressions and remove the valgrind stack traces / other valgrind output, and resolve .

Is there a way to do this easily?  This seems like a very basic use case...

```
// I want this part vvvvv
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: reachable
   fun:malloc
   fun:strdup
   fun:_XlcCreateLC
   fun:_XlcDefaultLoader
   fun:_XOpenLC
   fun:_XrmInitParseInfo
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
   fun:XrmGetStringDatabase
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
   fun:XGetDefault
   fun:GetXftDPI
   fun:X11_InitModes_XRandR
   fun:X11_InitModes
   fun:X11_VideoInit
}
// I do not want this part vvvv
==187526== 2 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 137
==187526==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==187526==    by 0x4B7C50E: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==187526==    by 0x5922D81: _XlcResolveLocaleName (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==187526==    by 0x5926387: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==187526==    by 0x5925956: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==187526==    by 0x592615C: _XlcCreateLC (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==187526==    by 0x5943664: _XlcDefaultLoader (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==187526==    by 0x592D995: _XOpenLC (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
```

Comment: (I'm aware of the `--log-file` option  - both the part I want and the part I don't want go into the log file with that option.)

Answer (score -1):

It is quite unlikely that all of the suppressions are different.

If you create a suppression like

```
{
   XINIT-1
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: reachable
   fun:malloc
   fun:strdup
   fun:_XlcCreateLC
   fun:_XlcDefaultLoader
   fun:_XOpenLC
   fun:_XrmInitParseInfo
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
}
```

Then re-run. Typically the error count will go down very quickly and you will only need to add a fairly small number of suppressions (single or low double digits).

(you need to apply your knowledge of the code and libs(s) to get a sensible stack depth for suppressions - too many stack entries and the suppression will be too specific and you need more suppressions, too few and you risk suppressing real problems).